# From google sheet app script Call js function resides in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have google chrome extension which has a function called `var jsonString = readCard()`
on running this method it read the smart card by interacting to USB card reader
and `jsonString` gets data.

from normal heml pages I am calling this as

```
var jsonString = readCard();
var jsonObj =JSON.parse(jsonString);
$('.txtName').val(jsonObj.name);
$('.txtPhone').val(jsonObj.phone);
```

But I want to call this funciton in Google sheet and instead of textboxes I want to populate data in google sheet.
I tried below but it says `referenceError: readCard is not defined`

my curren app code script is as below

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Smart Card')
      .addItem('Read Card', 'readCardFunction')
      .addToUi();
}

function readCardFunction() { 
  const data = readeid();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(data);
}
```

Comment: The extension should either add a second script in [the MAIN world](/a/9517879) with this function or it should implement [externally_connectable](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/messaging#external-webpage) or its content script should add a listener for some unique event id to which you can send a message via window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('foo', {detail: data}))